# PhoneGap application: "ERROR: Start Page at `www/index.html` was not found"

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created a Phone Gap based application on iPhone. After the first run, I have dragged my `www` folder, containing `index.html` into the project, but still I am getting the following error in the simulator:

> ERROR: Start Page at `www/index.html` was not found.

Do I have to mention the name of `index.html` in a plist file or anywhere else? How can I resolve this; can any one help me?

Comment: its a new project which i have created, there is no code in it and  i am not getting error while compiling but will get the above error on simulator

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's an incompatibility between PhoneGap and XCode 4. To resolve:

- right click on your project and choose "Add files to [project
  name]...";
- choose the `www` folder from your curent project's folder (it's
  included in there, but not added as a reference);
- when you select the folder, make sure you choose **"Copy items into
  destination group's folder"** as well as **"Create folder references for
  any added folders"**.

**Note:** if you choose "Create groups for any added folders", the app will still fail at runtime.

Answer (score 12):

For those who are as silly as me...
I had forgotten to run `cordova build`.

Comment: Similar to you, i had forgotten i did a gulp clean task so my www folder was empty.  Even though i was building, it wasn't copying anything.

Comment: Wow.. I'm pretty dumb too ._.

Comment: Very much silly as you xD

Answer (score 4):

Quit `XCode` and apply below command in terminal, its work for me

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the reference, and adding it again. Did you add it as a "Reference"? The icon should be in blue. Then clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just drop the www folder w/Finder into the Xcode Nav tab (root), after that just check dialog checkboxes "Copy items into destination group's folder" and "Create folder references for any added folders".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where it worked in the simulator but not a device.  My issue was case sensitivity.  My file was Index.html instead of lower case index.html.

Answer (score 1):

What versions of Xcode and PhoneGap are you using?

If you're using the older Xcode 3 and are creating a new project using the PhoneGap template... it should automatically create a `www` folder for you, along with a generic `index.html` file. If you've dragged your folder and index file **into** the project, then you should have been overwriting the existing files.

If you're using Xcode 4, there's a known issue with getting a PhoneGap project set up. It would be helpful to know what tutorial/guide you are following (assuming you are using a guide).

In very random cases, changes you make to your files/folders directly (via Finder) might not be picked up immediately by Xcode. You could always try quitting out of Xcode and re-opening your project, to ensure Xcode is pulling the latest files.

Answer (score 1):

Well `cordova build ios android` was the only thing that worked for me, and `cordova build` didn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

in xcode target - Copy Bundle Resource
add www folder

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by adding www to Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources