# Index.html not found on PhoneGap application when testing on a device

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created a small IPhone Application with PhoneGap (1.5), and I would now like to test it on my device.

I have set the output to my IPhone, and clicked build. The application is added, but I receive the following error when trying to run it on the phone:

> ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found.

It works fine if I try it on the simulator, so what might I have forgotten?

Comment: What vernon of Xcode and Phonegap are you using ?

Comment: whats  the path of index.html, add that

Comment: Try to clean the project, cmd+shift+k

Comment: Sorry Scitai but that didn't help either.

Comment: In my case it was a symlink on the `www` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there might have been an issue when I set up the application in the first place. First of all I saw that I referenced to an older version (1.4) of PhoneGap. I downloaded the newer version of the javascript component and replaced it, but it didn't help.

I then simply just created a new solution an copied the code from my old project and then it worked.

I am sorry to say that I don't know excately what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try to remove your www folder from your project and try to re-add it this way

[PhoneGap application: "ERROR: Start Page at `www/index.html` was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026285/phone-gap-application-error-start-page-at-www-index-html-was-not-found)

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. It works fine in the simulator, but not when loading onto the device.