# Getting error in configuring phonegap with xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova

I am trying to configure phonegap with xcode in my mac mini.
My Configuration :

- Mac OS X (10.6.8)
- Xcode 4.1

I followed the tutorial http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/52010495/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap-Cordova%20and%20Xcode%204. But I am getting error in compilation, I am not able to see Error : start page at 'www/index.html' not found instead I am getting following  error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey", referenced from:
      -[CDVFile setMetadata:withDict:] in Cordova
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please tell me how to configure phone gap in my xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added following line in AppDelegate.m file and this error get solved ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/1KePUPYywEk ).

```
NSString * const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = @"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey";
```

But now i am getting error www/index.html not found.

solved (see)
[PhoneGap application: "ERROR: Start Page at `www/index.html` was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026285/phone-gap-application-error-start-page-at-www-index-html-was-not-found)

Comment: Add www folder into your project