# 'www/index.html' was not found on the App Store

Tags: ios, cordova

I've created an iPad application with PhoneGap. It works fine when I test it on my iPad or when I send an ipa to an other iPad. I've sent app to the app Store, and the application have been validated. But, when someone download app and launch it, application still on splashscreen and have this error in log : "ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found."

I don't understand why there is a difference between test version and production version. What I can do to correct that.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Would this be of any help to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026285/phone-gap-application-error-start-page-at-www-index-html-was-not-found

Comment: In this example problem is at the first run, when I test on xcode I hav'nt this problem.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it works too for my problem, thanks !